# I can not change data receive from socket into integer. I get this error "invalid lateral for int () with base 10"

Tags: python, string, sockets, integer

I try to convert my variable data to integer .. i get this error "invalid lateral for int () with base 10" Thanks for help

```
import socket
import random
import re
import struct
def netcat(hostname, port):
    f= open("words.txt", "rb")
    l =f.readlines()
    i=0
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect((hostname, port))
    i=0
    while True:
        data = s.recv(2048)
        data=data.decode("utf-8")
        if data == "":
            break
        while int(data)<6:# my error 
            content=random.choice(l)
            print("sending: ",content)
            s.sendall(content)
            print ("the number of correct words: ", data)
    print ("Connection closed.")
    s.close()
```

Comment: display data before you try to convert to `int()` - it seems you get empty string or space. You may have to `strip()` it to remove spaces before `if data == "":`

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: Welcome to SO! This question could use minimization. Instead of showing all of your socket code, print whatever `data` is before the failed cast and ask about that. It should only be a couple lines, I'd think, if not just one. Otherwise, it's difficult to reproduce and too specific to this particular boilerplate. See [mcve] and don't forget to take the site [tour].

Comment: I try to remove space  ''.join(data.split() again the same error